# Disconected session Rad Studio XE2

Tags: x86-64, delphi-xe2

I have a problem when running a project on XE2 it sends me a "Session disconnected" error, this happens when I try to run the project on 64 bit. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Running the project without debugging runs it normally, but running with debugging is when it shows the error

Tried to install the IDE, update the IDE and it does not work

Error Message

> [20372E20]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.msgBox (Line 5902, "Debug.pas" + 30) + $0
> [04216EB3]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at DllUnregisterServer + $5037
> [0428B8A8]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $619D0
> [0428B927]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $61A4F
> [0428C36D]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62495
> [0428C5BD]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $626E5
> [042BC3E3]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9250B
> [04229D72]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at DllUnregisterServer + $17EF6
> [042BCEE2]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9300A
> [042BCBFB]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $92D23
> [042BCAD6]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $92BFE
> [042CF92B]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $A5A53
> [042BC19A]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $922C2
> [0428C7FC]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62924
> [0428CCCE]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62DF6
> [042ADA44]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $83B6C
> [04235E88]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $BFB0
> [042CF92B]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $A5A53
> [042C215A]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $98282
> [042C2AB4]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $98BDC
> [042C2043]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9816B
> [042C19A9]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $97AD1
> [04217CAE]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at DllUnregisterServer + $5E32
> [20371B1B]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.CreateProcess (Line 5427, "Debug.pas" + 17) + $63
> [2037F6AD]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.DoCreateProcess (Line 11628, "Debug.pas" + 74) + $3C
> [2037F820]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.CreateProcess (Line 11655, "Debug.pas" + 6) + $2F
> [20380373]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 12064, "Debug.pas" + 23) + $33
> [20380DEA]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 12389, "Debug.pas" + 129) + $43
> [2037AFE6]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 10045, "Debug.pas" + 0) + $2
> [2078C66D]{coreide160.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.Run (Line 1913, "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 3) + $B
> [500B5B9B]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line 13372, "System.Classes.pas" + 3) + $7
> [5031B86D]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.ActnList.TContainedAction.Execute (Line 448, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" + 8) + $2C
> [5031C658]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute (Line 1094, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" + 7) + $8
> [500B5A5F]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicActionLink.Execute (Line 13301, "System.Classes.pas" + 2) + $7
> [21714E79]{vclactnband160.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.ExecAction (Line 1076, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 6) + $D
> [217166F0]{vclactnband160.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 1842, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 19) + $15
> [2171A062]{vclactnband160.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMainMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 3636, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 5) + $3
> [21714A39]{vclactnband160.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.CMItemClicked (Line 955, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 3) + $4
> [50332995]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7204, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
> [503372F3]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152) + $6
> [21716806]{vclactnband160.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.WndProc (Line 1881, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 25) + $4
> [50336948]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
> [500B6890]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13878, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
> [50453213]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10164, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
> [50453256]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10194, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
> [50453595]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10332, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3

Comment: Any reason why you have not upgraded from an 11-year-old IDE? Which OS are you running on?

Comment: by dependencies that are compatible with xe2,